# Send File with extra parameters to WCF REST Service

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, wcf-rest

I am having a little problem here.

Currently I am using a Generic Handler to upload files to the server, but one problem that I have is that if I have extra data, like a user's name and surname, I have to do(save) that separately.

This is a problem, because if I save the name and surname, and the file upload fails, I have a record in my database that has no file associated with it.

So, now I am thinking of implementing a new web method, that will take all of this, and if that method fails, it will just roll back the SQL transaction.

What I want to do is call a web method, and pass the file with the user's name and surname and photo, and then perform the saving in the database there.

This is what I have tried:

jQuery:

```
$("#btnCreateRequest").click(function () {
    var data = new FormData();
    var photo = $("#fuPhoto")[0].files[0];

    data.append("name", 'Fred');
    data.append("surname", 'Moller');
    data.append("photo", photo);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Service.svc/CreateRequest",
        dataType: "json",
        //cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (response2) {
            //$("#PageArea").html(response2);
            Popup(true, "success", "success", true);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            Popup(true, "Error", JSON.stringify(response), true);
        }
    });
});
```

IService.cs

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "CreateRequest",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
string CreateRequest();
```

Service.svc

```
public string CreateRequest()
{
    var request = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;

    string name = request["name"];
    string surname = request["surname"];
    HttpPostedFile photo = request["photo"];

    //Saving in database happens here, using above variables...

    return "whatever";
}
```

However, I am failing miserably.

The web service gets called, but all the variables is NULL.

If I am going about this the wrong way, please point me in the right direction - any help will be appreciated!

(If something is not clear, please ask and I'll try to explain more)

Comment: try setting the `BodyStyle` to `Bare`.

Comment: Just tried that - it's still not getting the variable values :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, no matter, I've changed my approach. Instead of trying to use a Web Service, I now use the Generic Handler for this.

Sometimes, it's better to look at it a little different.
Here is how I got this to work for me.

In my jQuery, I will have something like this:

```
$("#btnCreateRequest").click(function () {
        var data = new FormData();
        var photo = $("#fuPhoto")[0].files[0];

        data.append("callingFromPage", "help");
        data.append("requestType", $('#dropBugType').val());
        data.append("description", $('#taDescription').val());
        data.append("photo", photo);
        data.append("userGUID", _cookieObject.UserObject.GlobalUniqueID);

        $.ajax({
            xhr: function () {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                        //Indicate progress.
                        $('.uplPhotoProgress').css('width', percentComplete + '%');
                        $('.uplPhotoProgress').html('Uploading: ' + percentComplete + '%');
                        //Hide progress bar.
                        if (percentComplete === 100) {
                            $//('.uplProgressAttachments').css('display', percentComplete + 'none');
                        }

                    }
                }, false);
                return xhr;
            },
            url: "UploadHandler.ashx/",
            data: data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response === 'success') {
                    console.log('success');
                } else {
                    console.log('problem...');
                }
            },
            error: function (response) {

            }
        });
    });
```

Then, in my UploadHandler.ashx (Generic Handler):

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
        context.Response.Expires = -1;
        try
        {
            string callingFromPage = context.Request["callingFromPage"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(callingFromPage))
            {
                switch (callingFromPage)
                {
                    case "help":
                        {
                            string requestType = context.Request["requestType"];
                            string description = context.Request["description"];
                            HttpPostedFile photo = context.Request.Files[0];
                            string guid = context.Request["userGUID"];
                            //DO YOUR STUFF >>>
                            context.Response.Write("success");
                            break;
                        }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Sure, this is a simple example of what I did... but I'm happy to do it this way.